# Practical attention models

Tags: attention-mechanism

[Attention is all you need](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762) is a nice paper that suggests using
*positional encodings* as an alternative to RNNs in their *Transformer* architecture.

GPT-2 and GPT-3 are examples of using this architecture which
are trained on input data of a massive scale.

Is there a paper and a model that uses positional encodings
and outcompetes RNN/LSTM based models for small scale datasets (MBs of text data, not terabytes)?

If there are many, which ones are the leading ones in production applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a paper and a model that uses positional encodings and outcompetes RNN/LSTM based models for small scale datasets (MBs of text data, not terabytes)?

Yes, there are several. Similar to GPT, they still pre-train on terabytes of data. But the embeddings they learn generalize well. Then you can fine-tune on a much smaller dataset. It works much in the same way as transfer learning on a CNN where a model first is trained on ImageNet and then trained on a specific task. It tends to give better results than RNN/LSTMs.

> If there are many, which ones are the leading ones in production applications?

The one that sees most use is definitely [BERT](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805). Here is a really nice [explanation](http://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-bert/) of how it works. This [transformers library](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) from Huggingface makes it really easy to work with BERT and other transformers that have already been pre-trained.